# Making kivy app executable

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, executable, cx-freeze

Ive created an executable file from kivy app i made.
The kivy app includes the following imports:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

import re
import pandas as pd
```

After making a set up file and running it it seems like the whole process went well with no problems, i can see the build folder with all the packages, but as soon as i run the executable file the app collapse.

here is my setup file:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("HR_specialist.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(

    name="HR_specialist",
    version='1.1',
    options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["kivy", "pandas", "re"]}},
    description="HR_specialist DEMO",
    executables=executables
)
```

If further information is needed please comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Kivy has a page on packaging for windows: [this one](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html). I'm not sure if cx_freeze works with kivy.

Answer (score 3):

I always use [the documented way](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html).

After PyInstaller created the .spec file I add:

```
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
```

in the second line 
and:

```
Tree('path to the folder where your main.py is'),
*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
```

after a.datas. This always worked for me. If you want to have less files use the "--onefile" argument and simply add additional files like .kv files in the folder of the executable.

Comment: Hi WTRipper, first thank you for answering...second, can you please explain what do you mean by saying "After PyInstaller created the .spec file" ...do i need to run pyinstaller first and then i get a spec file?

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for days!! the second line re: Tree solved my issue (Thank You!)